# Unix instruction to control access

Tags: unix, acl

i have this instruction

```
17 -rwxr-x-wx+ 1 john staff 2010 Jul 01 12:14 file3
```

What is 17, + and 1 in this instruction? Please help me ?

Answer (score 4):

The "+" indicates that there is an ACL (Access Control List) entry associated with the file. Use `getfacl` to view the ACLs. You can also use `setfacl` to set them.

The number "1" is the number of hard links to that file.

Comment: yes this is output from command "ls -l" but i don't understand exactly + for what is standing?

Comment: The + sign means that there is an ACL applied on top of the normal Unix permissions and that you need to use the getfacl command to see them.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement dogbanes's answer, the output you pasted is not an instruction, but a long output of `ls` command. The following command should give you full documentation of the `ls` command, including description of its output:

```
info coreutils 'ls invocation'
```

Try also `man ls`

The 17 *could be* the disk allocation size, displayed if `-s` option is used.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement dogbanes's and compostus' answers, if you happen to use ZFS or NFSv4 on Solaris, the proper way to display ACLs would be to use `ls -v` instead of `getfacl` and `chmod` instead of `setfacl`.